# How can you make your website load like youtube

Tags: html, backend

So my question is how can you make your website load like Youtube's and like other famous websites
because my website loads the traditional way. The traditional way of loading a website is that there this little thing going around the favicon of your website, like this [image].

So how do you make your website load like youtube's. Cause youtube's website doesnt have the thing going around there favicon else when you click a video there this thing on the top [image]

Answer (score 0):

Download topbar.js

```
<script src="topbar.js"></script>
```

Then you can customise the same

```
topbar.config({
  autoRun      : true,
  barThickness : 4,
  barColors    : {
      '0'      : 'rgba(26,  188, 156, .9)',
      '.25'    : 'rgba(52,  152, 219, .9)',
      '.50'    : 'rgba(241, 196, 15,  .9)',
      '.75'    : 'rgba(230, 126, 34,  .9)',
      '1.0'    : 'rgba(211, 84,  0,   .9)'
  },
  shadowBlur   : 10,
  shadowColor  : 'rgba(0,   0,   0,   .6)'
})
```

Show the bar with

```
topbar.show();
```

> nanobar.js is another alternative.